# ASP.Net , C# Web Application, how to play video sitting on client side

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a cloud based ASP.Net, C# Web Application.
I want the web application to invoke videos sitting on the clients's private network to play.

The client will have videos stored on their file server which is in their private network.
I want to play a video (via UNC path to video stored on the client's private network), the path (\fileserver\videos\xxxx.mp4) will be on the page as a hyper when a  user clicks that link the video will play in whatever compatible media player on the client PC. The client PC and file server are on the same network. The Cloud based application is hosted on a different network which is has no link to network of where the client PC and File Server is except via web.

I don't want to upload the videos to the web server and stream them back which is easy and works because of bandwidth issues. I just want to store the location of the video and invoke it to play via the web application (URL/file path which can be clicked on the page)

Is there a way for a web application to access files/resources on the client side in this case i want to play videos. If there is no out of the box functionality is there a work around please help.....

Comment: I don't think this can be done without using server side streaming. Would be happy to learn otherwise

Answer (score 0):

you can use HTML 5 element to play videos, is that what you meant ?

> ```
>  <video width="320" height="240" controls>
>      <source src="\fileserver\videos\xxxx.mp4" type="video/mp4">
>      <source src="\fileserver\videos\xxxx.ogg" type="video/ogg">
>      Your browser does not support the video tag.
>    </video>
> ```

Comment: Not Quite... I am not looking to stream the video and remember the videos on file server which is not on the same network as the Web Server, so i am looking for some form of client side code that takes the full path of the video and invokes it to play outside of the browser......

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.requestFileSystem() to access the client filesystem on chrome.
ActiveX on IE and Flash/Java on other browsers